# No Module Named 'delta.tables'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I am getting the following error for the code below, please help:

```
   from delta.tables import *
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delta.tables'
   INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Here is the code:
'''

```
   from pyspark.sql import *

   if __name__ == "__main__":
     spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("DeltaLake") \
        .config("spark.jars", "delta-core_2.12-0.7.0") \
        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
        .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
        .getOrCreate()

    from delta.tables import *

    data = spark.range(0, 5)

   data.printSchema()
```

'''

An online search suggesting verifying the scala version to delta core jar version. Here is the scala & Jar versions

"delta-core_2.12-0.7.0"

"Using Scala version 2.12.10, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_221"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to delta package [documentation](https://github.com/delta-io/delta), there is a python file named `tables`.
You should clone the repository and copy the `delta` folder under `python/delta` to your site packages path (i.e. `..\python37\Lib\site-packages`). then restart python and your code runs without the error.

I am using `Python3.5.3`,
`pyspark==3.0.1`,

Comment: Your answer helped. https://docs.delta.io/latest/quick-start.html    - Here is where it is

Comment: The provided link doesn't point to the correct repository. Take a look at https://github.com/delta-io/delta and you will see that `tables` actually exists within the delta Python package.

Comment: @Bram thanks answer modified with instructions on how to do it.

Answer (score 11):

or you can also

```
pip install delta-spark
```

[delta-spark pip page](https://pypi.org/project/delta-spark/)

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between `spark.jars` and `spark.jars.packages`. Since you are following the Quick Start, try replacing

```
.config("spark.jars", "delta-core_2.12-0.7.0")
```

with

```
.config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0")
```