# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delta.tables'; 'delta' is not a package

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I'm trying to get my PySpark to work with Delta table.

I did "pip install delta" as well as "pip install delta-spark"

This is my delta.py script:

```
from delta.tables import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "/tmp/delta-table")

# Update every even value by adding 100 to it
deltaTable.update(
  condition = expr("id % 2 == 0"),
  set = { "id": expr("id + 100") })

# Delete every even value
deltaTable.delete(condition = expr("id % 2 == 0"))

# Upsert (merge) new data
newData = spark.range(0, 20)

deltaTable.alias("oldData") \
  .merge(
    newData.alias("newData"),
    "oldData.id = newData.id") \
  .whenMatchedUpdate(set = { "id": col("newData.id") }) \
  .whenNotMatchedInsert(values = { "id": col("newData.id") }) \
  .execute()

deltaTable.toDF().show()
```

Here is my spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0  --master local[*] --executor-memory 2g delta.py
```

Here is the output containing the error:

```
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/mnt/spark/jars/ivy-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/eugene/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/eugene/.ivy2/jars
io.delta#delta-core_2.12 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-c6184f38-2d95-498c-b711-ead1c4e98cdc;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found io.delta#delta-core_2.12;0.7.0 in central
    found org.antlr#antlr4;4.7 in central
    found org.antlr#antlr4-runtime;4.7 in central
    found org.antlr#antlr-runtime;3.5.2 in central
    found org.antlr#ST4;4.0.8 in central
    found org.abego.treelayout#org.abego.treelayout.core;1.0.3 in central
    found org.glassfish#javax.json;1.0.4 in central
    found com.ibm.icu#icu4j;58.2 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 1363ms :: artifacts dl 24ms
    :: modules in use:
    com.ibm.icu#icu4j;58.2 from central in [default]
    io.delta#delta-core_2.12;0.7.0 from central in [default]
    org.abego.treelayout#org.abego.treelayout.core;1.0.3 from central in [default]
    org.antlr#ST4;4.0.8 from central in [default]
    org.antlr#antlr-runtime;3.5.2 from central in [default]
    org.antlr#antlr4;4.7 from central in [default]
    org.antlr#antlr4-runtime;4.7 from central in [default]
    org.glassfish#javax.json;1.0.4 from central in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   8   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   8   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-c6184f38-2d95-498c-b711-ead1c4e98cdc
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 8 already retrieved (0kB/16ms)
23/01/28 14:44:02 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eugene/dev/pyspark/delta.py", line 1, in <module>
    from delta.tables import *
  File "/home/eugene/dev/pyspark/delta.py", line 1, in <module>
    from delta.tables import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delta.tables'; 'delta' is not a package
23/01/28 14:44:02 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
23/01/28 14:44:02 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-a8e1196f-83c5-4c81-865e-9522d4d0c056
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Should be `pip` or `pip3`? Please make sure the package is installed to the proper Python version (used by Spark), in case if you have multiple versions running on the system.

Comment: I believe I am doing it the proper way. Please take a look:   (venv) eugene@Linux-Spark-Kafka:~/dev/pyspark$ pip list
Package            Version
------------------ --------
delta              0.4.2
delta-spark        2.2.0
importlib-metadata 6.0.0
pip                22.3.1
py4j               0.10.9.5
pyspark            3.3.1
setuptools         58.1.0
zipp               3.12.0
>>> from delta.tables import *

    from delta.tables import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'delta.tables'; 'delta' is not a package

Comment: Hope you have not missed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65553722/no-module-named-delta-tables

Comment: If you are using a virtual environment then need to look around it, is it installed in `venv`?

Comment: uninstall `delta`. Also, what is Apache Spark version? Delta 0.7.0 is ancient version, and won't work with the latest Spark versions

Comment: Apache Spark is at version 3.3.1