# error "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot find catalog plugin class for catalog 'spark_catalog': org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"

Tags: pyspark

Issue description:

Facing below error while trying to execute code below. The code is written to read a csv file into dataframe and down the line looking to create Delta Table.

**Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o95.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot find catalog plugin class for catalog 'spark_catalog': org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog**

Jupyter notebook, Spark(3.3.3), Java(17.0.8), Python 3.10.13

sample code:

```
import findspark

findspark.init()
findspark.find()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = (SparkSession.builder.appName("DeltaLakeApp").master("local[4]")
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled","false")
    #add package for delta lake
    .config("spark.jars.package","io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.4.0")
    #add settings to use delta lake with Spark session
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog","org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")         
    .getOrCreate()
    )
    sc = spark.sparkContext`

    taxiDF = (spark.read.option("hearder", "true").option("inferSchema", "true")
    .csv("C:\DataFiles\Raw\Taxis_01.csv"))
```

Tried loading packages below but never installed but failed.

spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.3,io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.4.0 kafka_to_delta.py

Comment: Included delta folder from the cloned repository from Gitbub as suggested in the link below. however it did not worked and issue remains same.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65553722/no-module-named-delta-tables